# jQuery User Sign-In Popup Box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, popup

I have a module list which shows all the modules available (retrieve from database). For every module, there will be a "subscribe" button. What I want to achieve is that when user click "subscribe" before logging into the account, the page will pop up a sign in box and let user sign in. Whereas if he has already signed in and click "subscribe", this module should be added to his record in the database.

**module_list.php**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <link href="css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/default.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
<?php
          /* this part of code checks whether user has signed in. If he has, $_POST['userid'] will contain something, and checkuser will have value 1 (since userid is unique) */ 
                $user = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid = '".$POST['userid']."'");    
                        $checkuser = mysql_num_rows($user);
                        if ($checkuser != 1)   // if checkuser is not 1 (user hasnt signed in), pop up sign in box
                        {
                    ?>
                            <div class="popup"> 
                            <a href="#" class="close">CLOSE</a>
                            <form>
                                <p><span class="title">Username</span> <input name="" type="text" /></p>
                                <p><span class="title">Password</span> <input name="" type="password" /></p>
                                <p><input name="" type="button" value="Login" /></p>
                            </form>
                            </div>
                    <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
                    <?php
                        }
                        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM module"); 
                        while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
                        {
                            echo '<div id="middle">';
                            echo '<div id="title_prof"><a href="module.php?module='.$result['code'].'">'.$result['code'].' '.$result['name'].'</a><br />';
                            $profid = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM teach WHERE modulecode = '".$result['code']."'");
                            $profidresult = mysql_fetch_array($profid);
                            $checkprofid = mysql_num_rows($profid);
                            if ($checkprofid == 1)
                            {
                                $prof = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM prof WHERE profid = '".$profidresult['profid']."'");
                                $profresult = mysql_fetch_array($prof);
                                echo '<i> by '.$profresult['name'].'</i></div>';
                                echo '<div id="date_button"> created on: '.substr($result['date'], 0, 10);
                                echo '<br /><input type="submit" id="subscribe" value="Subscribe" /></div>';
                            }

                            echo '</div>';
                            echo '<hr>';

                        }

                    ?>
                    </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

This is the jQuery needed to trigger the pop up: **default.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#subscribe').click(function() {
          $("body").append('<div class="overlay"></div>');
        $(".popup").show();

        $(".close").click(function(e) {
            $(".popup, .overlay").hide();
        });
    });
```

The problem is, when I press "subscribe" button, the page refreshes but **pop up is not showing**. I am new to jQuery and I suspect the problem maybe due to my js code. Anyone can shed some lights here?

Answer (score 0):

When a submit button is pressed inside the form the default event is to submit the form to the server. To prevent the default event you could try,

```
$('#subscribe').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();//prevent form submission.
  ................... // your code
}
```

Comment: thank you but its not working. Initially I actually used `<input type=""button"` but its not working as well so I dont think is due to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Look into jquery dialog.  Sounds like this will do exactly what u want. Link : 
[jquery dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/)